# How to not break Cypress tests if element you'r looking for is not exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, cypress

I have the div with classname 'okrSelectorSelect__value-container' in DOM.

```
<div class="okrSelectorSelect__value-container"><div>
```

This div is **optional**. I want to click on it and do some additional tests with block that appears after that **IF IT EXIST**.
I'm trying this.

```
cy.get('.okrSelectorSelect__value-container').then(($higherObjectivePick) => {
 if ($higherObjectivePick.length > 0) {
  $higherObjectivePick.click();
 }
});
```

But got this when block is not on the page

[image]

Here is my solution, but looks like there is much more beautiful ways to do that.

```
 cy.get('body').then($body => {
    if ($body.find('.okrSelectorSelect__value-container').length > 0) { 
      cy.get('.okrSelectorSelect__value-container').click();
      cy.get('.okrSelectorSelect__option').eq(higherOrderObjectiveNumber).click();
    }
  });
```

Comment: How about writing two different tests for two different ways?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do the same like you but it would be more pretty to create a custom command for it like this:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("clickIfExists",(containerId , ItemId)=>{
  cy.get('body').then($body => {
    if ($body.find(containerId).length > 0) { 
      cy.get(ItemId).click();
    }
  }); 
})
```

and by this way you can always call it like that if you would like to click on `.okrSelectorSelect__option` :

```
cy.clickIfExists(".okrSelectorSelect__value-container",".okrSelectorSelect__option")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery operators to check the existence of an element and wrap that function as below, adding to your support.js file:

```
Cypress.Commands.add("checkIfClassExists", (classToFind) => {
    return Cypress.$(classToFind).length>0
})
```

Then in your tests:

```
if (cy.checkIfClassExists('.okrSelectorSelect__value-container')) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do nothing 
}
```